# How to get the values from the previous column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the revenue of a sale of each country and then also the percentage of the total revenue each country makes up, I've calculated the revenue but I can't get the percentage value. Here's my code,

```
/*Which countries have the highest sales revenue? What percent of total revenue does each country make up*/
SELECT Invoice.BillingCountry, SUM(Invoice.Total) AS Revenue
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY Invoice.BillingCountry
ORDER BY Revenue DESC;
```

This is the result that I get,

| Billing Country | Revenue | Percentage of Total Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 523.06 |  |
| Canada | 303.96 |  |
| France | 195.10 |  |
| Brazil | 190.10 |  |
| Germany | 156.48 |  |

But how do I get the percentage value of each country's revenue? Is there a way to fetch the values of the 'revenue' column from my query so that I can calculate the percentage by (revenue/total revenue)*100 ?

Comment: `ORDER BY 'Revenue' DESC;` isn't going to do anything. `'Revenue'` is a literal string, so the order is going to be completely arbitrary.

Comment: And as Gordon said below, there is no need to escape revenue.  If you do need to escape an alias or column name, for SQL Server, use double quotes or square brackets.  Or, much better, don't use reserved words as column/alias names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT i.BillingCountry, SUM(i.Total) as Revenue,
       SUM(i.Total) * 1.0 / SUM(SUM(i.Total)) OVER () as Revenue_proportion
FROM Invoice i
GROUP BY i.BillingCountry
ORDER BY Revenue DESC;
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column names.  `Revenue` is a fine name and doesn't need to be escaped.